# ora-12528: TNS:Listener: All Appropriate instances are blocking new connections

Tags: oracle

I am getting this error when I try to connect to my database:

> ora-12528: TNS:Listener: All Appropriate instances are blocking new connections

I tried the following, with no success:

1. Stop and Start the Listener.
2. Shutdown and Startup database.
3. Restart the oracle services.

How might I resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

You might have a problem with either the network and/or the archive logs - the above usually happens when the area/disk where the archive logs are stored is full, Oracle then just refuses new connections.

Another possibility is that you maxed out the number of allowed connections - this should usually be warning sign that you might have an application which leaks connections.

If you are 100% sure that you are not leaking connections then you could configure Oracle to accept more connections (BEWARE of licensing, RAM etc.!).

Comment: I remember running into this problem because a reminder application written by our .net team kept creating new connections every half hour or so and never bothered releasing them.. Yikes!